# sed replacing without untouching a string

Tags: variables, replace, sed

Im trying to replace all lines within files that contains:

**/var/www/webxyz/html**

to

**/home/webxyz/public_html**

the string: **webxyz** is variable: like web1, web232

So only the string before and after **webxyz** should be replaced.
Tried this without solution:

```
sed -i 's/"var/www/web*/html"/"home/web*/public_html"/g'
```

Also i want this should check and replace files (inclusive subdirectory and files),
the * operator don't work.

Comment: The `*` operator means "zero to many of the thing before me."  You cannot use it except as a literal in the final string.  You should research how `sed` uses `match` variables.  Also, there is no need for double-quote characters within the `s/.../.../g` statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Within a regular expression, you’ll need to escape the delimiting character that surround them, in your case the `/`. But you can also use a different delimiter like `,`:

```
sed -i 's,"var/www/web*/html","home/web*/public_html",g'
```

But to get it working as intended, you’ll also need to remove the `"` and replace the `b*` (sed doesn’t understand globbing wildcards) to something like this:

```
sed -i 's,var/www/web\([^/]*\)/html,home/web\1/public_html,g'
```

Here `\([^/]*\)` is used to match anything after `web` except a `/`. The matching string is then referenced by `\1` in the replacement part.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what your replacement operation should look like (see [sed](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#uh-8) for more info):

```
sed -i 's/var\/www\(\/.*\/\)html/home\1public_html/g'
```

Note that `\(...\)` is a grouping, and specifies a "match variable" which shows up in the replacement side as `\1`.  Note also the `.*` which says "match any single character (dot) zero or more times (star)".  Note further that your `/` characters must be escaped so that they are not treated as part of the `sed` control structure.